# Slow flushing (sending) of events

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, async-await, azure-application-insights

We are using Application Insights today to track events in our WPF solution.

Since this is a desktop we need to manually call the flush method.

Since we don't track an heap of events we keep flushing whenever an event come.

What we realised is that the flush method is very slow. What we've now done is moved this flush call to another thread, and hence need to keep alot of locks and checks, extra code.

Looking into the application insights code it comes down to these two methods:

```
private void DequeueAndSend()
    {
        lock (this.sendingLockObj)
        {
            IEnumerable<ITelemetry> telemetryItems = this.buffer.Dequeue();
            try
            {
                // send request
                this.Send(telemetryItems).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CoreEventSource.Log.LogVerbose("DequeueAndSend: Failed Sending: Exception: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes a list of telemetry items and sends them.
    /// </summary>
    private async Task Send(IEnumerable<ITelemetry> telemetryItems)
    {
        if (telemetryItems == null || !telemetryItems.Any())
        {
            CoreEventSource.Log.LogVerbose("No Telemetry Items passed to Enqueue");
            return;
        }

        byte[] data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(telemetryItems);
        var transmission = new Transmission(this.endpointAddress, data, "application/x-json-stream", JsonSerializer.CompressionType);

        await transmission.SendAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Looking specificly at this line:

```
            this.Send(telemetryItems).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Not sure I'm getting this right but wouldn't the GetResult() make this method synchronous, if so, why is it implemented this way?

If not, what might be the reason for the Flush() method to be so slow?

Comment: Which SDKs (including versions) are you using?

Comment: i believe it is synchronous because the assumption was if you are explicitly calling flush, you're doing it because the app is shutting down or something and you want to (try to) guarantee those events are sent.  If the call wasn't synchronous, then the app could shut down before the async call completed.

Comment: @JohnGardner is correct. Flush is designed to allow you to send all telemetry before you shutdown and therefore needs to be synchronous. For general sending of data. You might consider using the PersistenceChannel instead of the default in-memory channel as described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/

Comment: Thats for the respons. Looking at that page @Luke there is an example that says in the code:  // Allow time for flushing:
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  Is this then needed since it's synchronous? It also mentions in the persistence channel: "Note that Flush() is synchronous for the persistence channel, but asynchronous for other channels." I guess this is wrong then? Final question, looking at my usecase, flushing whenever a log gets in, how would you have done in my situation? Thanks